# mysql bit-operations performance

Tags: mysql, performance, bit

&I need to compare looooong bit-sequences (up to 1000 digits) with each other, currently I've got a table with 16 columns (16*64 = 1024):

```
userid       block_1      block_2       block_3      ...
     1       1001...      1100...       0010...
     2       1101...      1011...       0111...
     3       1011...      0111...       1100...
```

my statement:

```
select sh.userid,
    sum(bit_count(se.block_1 & sh.block_1)+bit_count(se.block_2 & sh.block_2)+...)
    from my_table se, my_table sh
    where se.userid = 1
    and se.userId != sh.userId 
    group by sh.userId
```

With about 5 million entries, the query time is ~ 1.5 seconds, which is already pretty good, I guess. Most of the time is lost for the bit_count- and &-part, therefore I'm asking myself if there's some room for improvement.

Is there a better way to compare very long binary sequences?

**EDIT**

I'm expecting the se.block_X to contain much more 0s than sh.block_X; does it make a difference if I do

```
se.block_X & sh.block_X
or
sh.block_X & se.block_X
```

? I would expect the first one to be faster.

the `1` and `0` represent `yes` and `no` in a lot of categories and I'm only interested in where BOTH entries said `yes`. So

```
10101011100101011
        &
10010101101001010
=================
10000001100001010
```

and now I now where both of them said yes. For my use case I have to compare e.g. my answers with ~ 5 millions of entries of others answers, and there are about 1000 questions. So I've got a table with 5 million entries, each with 16x64 bit columns. And then I have to compare 1 of the entry to all the others basically.

Comment: What ^-part? Where are you comparing long binary sequences?

Comment: sorry, I meant the ```&``` part (edited my question). I'm comparing the binary sequences in ```se.block_1 & sh.block_1``` etc.

Comment: where's the comparison?  I only see you counting the number of set bits?  Ah - the `&` of `sh` vs `se`.  I see...   Did you really only want to consider the sequences as equal if both bits are set?  I would have expected an `xor` operation if you want to check for equality.

Comment: or if perhaps you're trying to calculate the hamming distance between them?

Comment: OK, that's clearer and explains the `&` vs `^`.  As to `se & sh` vs `sh & se` - there'll be no difference - "anding" is an `O(1)` operation and it makes no difference what the relative distribution of the set bits is in the operands.

Comment: but if the first operand is a ```0```, the second doesn'T have to be checked, therefore I would expect it to be faster.

Comment: That's a potential optimisation but one that's unlikely to be taken because sometimes the _test_ and branch for zero takes longer than just performing the 'and' - the latter being one of the simplest and most fundamental operations on a CPU.  I'm looking at the MariaDB source code and the `BIT_COUNT` implementation appears potentially inefficient.

Comment: i.e. it splits each 64 bit word into bytes, and then uses a pre-calculated lookup table to map from each byte to the number of bits, adding those up.  There are "bit twiddling hacks" around that require far fewer operations.